# Hook not trigger

Tags: wordpress, hook

I am new to wordpress and I can not find a way to make any hook work.
I use a child theme with this function.php

```
<?php
function custom_callback_function(){
    // add your custom code here to do something
    echo 'I will be fired on WordPress initialization';
}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_callback_function' );
?>
```

I tried different hook, placing the add_action above the function name.
Does not matter, does not work.

Thank you for any help/

EDIT:

```
    <?php

function custom_callback_function(){
    // add your custom code here to do something
    echo 'I will be fired on WordPress initialization';
}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_callback_function' );

// show a maintenance message for all your site visitors
add_action( 'get_header', 'maintenance_message' );
function maintenance_message() {
    wp_die( '<h1>Stay Pawsitive!</h1><br>Sorry, we\'re temporarily down for maintenance right meow.' );
}
```

I tried to change my function file like this (no more closing tag) but no luck.

I tried to create a new page but it didn't change a thing.
Should the function.php file be referred somewhere ?

Answer (score 1):

When you write functions, you can assign them a priority, which tells WordPress when to run them.

By default, WordPress assigns a priority of 10 to functions which haven't had a priority added, if you want to fire your function after it, you use a number larger than 10.

A function in your parent theme may have a priority assigned to it. So you want to make sure the priority you give the function in your child theme is higher.

```
function custom_callback_function(){
    // add your custom code here to do something
    echo 'I will be fired on WordPress initialization';
}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_callback_function', 20 );
```

Comment: Thx for your answer however it does not change the result.
I am trying to do this: https://kinsta.com/blog/wordpress-hooks/#example-of-hooking-an-action
But when loading the main page of my site I see nothing.

Comment: try a lower priority like 9

Comment: Same result. Is there a way to have a debug mode for hook ? I feel there are not called at all.